# How to edit package functions in R?

Tags: r, debugging, upsetr

I would like to make subtle changes to a visualisation from the UpSetR package. Within the `upset()` function there is another sub-function called `Make_size_plot()` that creates the bar chart which I would like to change.

```
library(UpSetR)
```

I figured using the `trace()` function would be one way to do it.

```
trace(upset, edit=T)
```

However, I only managed to edit the `upset()` function but not the `Make_size_plot()` function on line 162 within the `upset()` function.

How can I edit the `Make_size_plot()` function the easiest way, e.g. without creating my own package or forking the Github repo?

Comment: What do you ned this for? As a general rule this kind of editing is an *extremely bad idea*. Any update to the original package can completely break your own code. For almost all use-cases it would be better to for the original code and edit the fork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
trace(UpSetR:::Make_size_plot, edit=T)
```

Comment: will it replace the original code permanently or temporarily?